# Python - Splitting multiple values in list to different rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my dataset as below:

```
bill_id, prodname
101,['apples','oranges']
102,['bananas','oranges']
103,['apples']
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
101,apples
101,oranges
101,bananas
101,oranges
101,apples
```

Could anyone assist on how I could split these values into multiple rows for the same bill_id. Thanks

Comment: Do you want all 101 or [101, 101, 102, 102, 103]?

Comment: @DanielMesejo  I would want to do this for all elements in the Dataframe

Comment: So you want to set bill_id all to 101?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Nope just the values in the Dataframe to be converted..

Comment: Converted to what? In your output example all the values of bill_id are set to 101